# Robot Framework : Unable to use functions from custom libraries

Tags: python, robotframework

I have recently started building a Robot framework in python. I was able to work through the inbuilt keywords successfully and run sample tests with it as well. Now when I moved to some complex test cases, I decided to create custom libraries.

My idea was to have a generic utility with wrapper functions such as `wait_and_click`, `click_and_wait_for_element`, `scroll_to_element_and_set focus` etc utilizing builtin selenium keywords in some combination.
Also to utilize POM , I created custom libraries for individual pages as well to separate the custom page logic from generic wrappers.

Issue I am facing is when I run the test case, I get an error `AttributeError: module 'src.genericlibs.SupportUtils' has no attribute 'wait_and_click'`

This issue is coming only for page custom libraries but not for generic utility.

Generic Utility (src.genericlibs.SupportUtils.py)

```
from robot.api.deco import library, keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn


@library
class SupportUtils:

    def __init__(self):
        self.builtin = BuiltIn()
        self.selLib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SeleniumLibrary")
        self.jsonLib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("JSONLibrary")
        self.osLib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("OperatingSystem")

    @keyword
    def set_focus_and_wait_to_scroll_to_element(self, locator, wait_time):
        self.selLib.set_focus_to_element(locator)
        self.selLib.wait_until_element_is_enabled(locator, wait_time)
        self.builtin.run_keyword_and_ignore_error('self.selLib.execute_javascript',
                                                  'arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);',
                                                  locator)

    @keyword
    def wait_and_click(self, locator, wait_time):
        self.selLib.set_focus_to_element(locator)
        self.selLib.sleep(2)
        self.selLib.wait_until_element_is_enabled(locator, wait_time)
        self.selLib.click_element(locator)
        self.selLib.sleep(2)

    @keyword
    def click_and_wait_for(self, primary_locator, secondary_locator, wait_time):
        self.selLib.wait_until_element_is_enabled(primary_locator, wait_time)
        self.selLib.set_focus_to_element(primary_locator)
        self.selLib.click_element(primary_locator)
        self.selLib.wait_until_element_is_enabled(secondary_locator, wait_time)

    @keyword
    def wait_and_enter_text(self, locator, text, wait_time):
        self.selLib.wait_until_element_is_enabled(locator, wait_time)
        self.selLib.click_element(locator)
        self.selLib.input_text(locator, text)

    @keyword
    def read_data_from_json_file(self, filepath):
        input_data = self.osLib.get_file(filepath)
        if input_data is None:
            self.builtin.log(f"Failed to find content in File {filepath}")
        input_data_json = self.builtin.evaluate(input_data)
        self.builtin.log(f"These are the contents of the JSON File :\n {input_data_json}")
        return input_data_json

    @keyword
    def get_node_value_from_json(self, json_data, json_node):
        input_data_json = self.builtin.evaluate(str(json_data))
        json_value = self.jsonLib.get_value_from_json(input_data_json, json_node)
        self.builtin.log(f"This is the Node Value for Json Node {json_node} : {json_value}")
        return json_value
```

Custom Page Libraries (src.pageutils.ContactUtils.py)

```
from robot.api.deco import library, keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from src.genericlibs import SupportUtils

next_recordType = "//span[text()='Next']"
contact_account = "//*[text()='Account Name']" \
                  "/parent::lightning-grouped-combobox" \
                  "//input[@placeholder='Search Accounts...']"
contact_email = "//input[@name='Email']"
contact_phone = "//input[@name='Phone']"
contact_fname = "//input[@name='firstName']"
contact_lname = "//input[@name='lastName']"
contact_saveInfo = "//button[text()='Save']"


@library
class ContactUtils:

    def __init__(self):
        self.builtin = BuiltIn()
        self.supportutils = SupportUtils


    @keyword
    def create_contact(self, contact_info: list, wait_time: int):
        contact_info = contact_info[0]
        self.builtin.log(contact_info)
        self.supportutils.wait_and_click(next_recordType, wait_time)
        self.supportutils.set_focus_and_wait_to_scroll_to_element(contact_email, wait_time)
        self.supportutils.wait_and_enter_text(contact_email, contact_info[email])
        self.supportutils.set_focus_and_wait_to_scroll_to_element(contact_phone, wait_time)
        self.supportutils.wait_and_enter_text(contact_phone, contact_info[phone])
        self.supportutils.set_focus_and_wait_to_scroll_to_element(contact_fname, wait_time)
        self.supportutils.wait_and_enter_text(contact_fname, contact_info[first_name])
        self.supportutils.wait_and_enter_text(contact_lname, contact_info[last_name])
        self.supportutils.wait_and_enter_text(contact_account, contact_info[account_name])
        account_dropdown_locator = "//ul[@role='group']" \
                                   "//lightning-base-combobox-formatted-text[@title='"+contact_account_value+"']"
        self.supportutils.wait_and_click(account_dropdown_locator, wait_time)
        self.supportutils.wait_and_click(contact_saveInfo, wait_time)
        self.builtin.set_test_variable("contact_first_name", contact_firstname)
        self.builtin.set_test_variable("contact_last_name", contact_lastname)
```

Robot Test (src.tests.QuoteCreationTest.robot)

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation                   This test contains steps to create quote in SFDC
Library                         SeleniumLibrary
Library                         String
Library                         JSONLibrary
Library                         OperatingSystem
Library                         ../genericlibs/SupportUtils.py
Library                         ../pageUtils/ContactUtils.py
Library                         ../pageUtils/OpportunityUtils.py
Resource                        ../pageobjects/loginpage.resource
Resource                        ../pageobjects/homepage.resource
Resource                        ../pageobjects/accountpage.resource
Resource                        ../pageobjects/contactpage.resource
Resource                        ../pageobjects/opportunitypage.resource
Resource                        ../pageobjects/quotepage.resource
Resource                        ../pageobjects/datareader.resource


*** Variables ***
${filepath} =                           C:\\Users\\kovid_mehta\\PycharmProjects\\RobotFramework\\src\\data\\test_data_quote.json


*** Test Cases ***
Validate quote creation in SFDC
    user fetches data from json file and set the contents in test variable                                    ${filepath}
    ${username_value}=              user fetches json node value from json        ${test_data}                $.Aus_User_Quote.pilot.username
    ${password_value}=              user fetches json node value from json        ${test_data}                $.Aus_User_Quote.pilot.password
    ${account_data}=                user fetches json node value from json        ${test_data}                $.Aus_User_Quote.account_data
    ${account_name}=                user fetches json node value from json        ${account_data[0]}          $.name
    ${account_currency}=            user fetches json node value from json        ${account_data[0]}          $.currency
    ${account_region}=              user fetches json node value from json        ${account_data[0]}          $.region
    ${contact_data}=                user fetches json node value from json        ${test_data}                $.Aus_User_Quote.contact_data
    ${contact_info_list} =          Create List                                   ${contact_data[0]}
    ${opportunity_data}=            user fetches json node value from json        ${test_data}                $.Aus_User_Quote.opportunity_data
    ${opportunity_info_list} =      Create List                                   ${opportunity_data[0]}
#
    User logs in successfully to SFDC Environment                                 ${username_value[0]}        ${password_value[0]}
    User Verifies SFDC Home Page Post Login
    User clicks on Account tab from Home Page
    User clicks on New Account
    User enters the required Account information                                  ${account_name[0]}
    User verifies account creation in SFDC
    Sleep                                                                         10
    User goes to contact page in SFDC
    Sleep                                                                         10
    User clicks on New Contact
    Create Contact                                                                ${contact_info_list}          60
    User verifies contact information in SFDC
    Sleep                                                                         10
    User goes to opportunity page in SFDC
    Sleep                                                                         10
    User clicks on New Opportunity
    Create Opportunity                                                            ${opportunity_info_list}      60
    User verifies Opportunity information in SFDC
```

Execution comes to "Create Contact" step and then fails with above error on line - `self.supportutils.wait_and_click(next_recordType, wait_time)`.
I tried wrapping Create Contact under a keyword in src.pageobjects.contactpage.resources as well but it resulted in same error.

Please help me in understanding the mistake and point to existing documents if any.

Comment: You are storing a reference to SupportUtils but you never call the class constructor ..